# koa2 template string can not display properly

Tags: koa2

I am installing coat 2.0 and node 8.0, but when I test following code, it shows
Hello World ${date}, not Hello World 6/7/2017.

const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

app.use(ctx => {

```
const date = new Date();

ctx.body = 'Hello World ${date}';
```

});

app.listen(3000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks ` in a template string:

```
const Koa = require('koa'); const app = new Koa();

app.use(ctx => {
    const date = new Date();
    ctx.body = `Hello World ${date}`;
});

app.listen(3000);
```